# Place image on canvas at same x,y position as mouse onclick

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, onclick, coordinates

I'm trying to make a web app that lets the user insert small images of characters on an html canvas. The plan is to have the user click a button on a virtual keyboard, and then click on the canvas to have the corresponding character appear wherever the user clicked. Right now I'm just trying to get one image to appear on the canvas when clicked, but so far it isn't doing anything. Here's the code I have now, which is embedded in the html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var mathCanvas = document.getElementById("matharea");
            var ctx = mathCanvas.getContext("2d");
            var el = mathCanvas;
            var xPos = 0;
            var yPos = 0;
            while(el && !isNaN(el.offsetLeft) && !isNaN(el.offsetTop)){
                xPos += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
                yPos += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
                el = el.parentNode;
            }
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = "five.png";
            mathCanvas.onclick = function(event){
                var x = event.clientX - xPos;
                var y = event.clientY - yPos;
                ctx.drawImage(img,x,y);
            };
</script>
```

I've tested the onclick event, and it returns coords, but the image won't appear. What's going wrong here?

Comment: `img.src = "/absolute/path/to/image.png";`

Comment: inside your `onclick` handler, do a `console.log(x,y);` and post the result here.

Comment: that said, since you're registering the click event on the canvas itself, you should be able to simply use `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY`, and disregard the rest of your offset handling code.

Answer (score 3):

This should work since the click event will be firing on the canvas itself:

```
        var mathCanvas = document.getElementById("matharea");
        var ctx = mathCanvas.getContext("2d");

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "five.png";
        mathCanvas.onclick = function(event){
            var x = event.offsetX;
            var y = event.offsetY;
            ctx.drawImage(img,x,y);
        };
```

To center the image on the point:

```
        var mathCanvas = document.getElementById("matharea");
        var ctx = mathCanvas.getContext("2d");

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "five.png";
        mathCanvas.onclick = function(event){
            var x = Math.round(event.offsetX - img.width/2);
            var y = Math.round(event.offsetY - img.height/2);
            ctx.drawImage(img,x,y);
        };
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working but it's placing the image file down and to the right of the click, and it's also enlarging the image.

Comment: Do you want the image to be centered on the clicked point? drawImage draws from the top-left. Also, from the code posted, there's no reason it shouldn't be the same scale as the actual image. Are you resizing the canvas with CSS? Are you scaling the canvas? (`ctx.transform(...);`)

Comment: I'd like the click to draw from the top-left, and the .png I'm using is only 8x14 pixels, but it's pushing it a long ways away from the click point. And I've specified a width and height of the canvas in CSS, should I be doing that in the html canvas tag?

Comment: Yeah. The width and height should be defined on the canvas itself. If you specify a different width in CSS, it will stretch the canvas.

Comment: Here's a demo of how mis-matching width/height defined in CSS can bugger everything: http://jsfiddle.net/mRZn8/